# Windows 7: Strange behavior of console commands. Windows understand Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, console

Somehow, my **Windows 7** started tp understand Linux commands like `cp`, `mv`, `rm`, `ls`

While it has been useful  I want to know, what is it and what do I need to install for this feature?

Comment: I suspect that you may be using the powershell prompt rather than the cmd console. Powershell ships with W7 and has aliases baked in for many *nix commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is that you have installed the [GnuWin32 tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GnuWin32), which provide ports of common Linux programs to Windows. You might have installed another program that bundles GnuWin32 and added it to your `%PATH%`.

Another possibility (as @EBGreen pointed out in the comments) is that you are now in the [Powershell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) prompt, where you were previously using [`cmd.exe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Prompt_(Windows)). Powershell provides aliases for common Unix programs, including `cp`, `mv`, `rm`, and `ls`; [here's a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Windows_PowerShell&oldid=502858384#Comparison_of_cmdlets_with_similar_commands).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what exactly you're asking. But it looks like you want a way to use Linux commands with Windows?

FYI: The ability to use different commands are part of your operating system's (OS) command interpreter.

Typically, Linux (and other xNIX's) use the "C-Shell." But that's not what Microsoft uses since they use their own command interpreter - command.com. But I do believe you can change it! However, you may want to just get Microsoft's latest "Power Shell" upgrade/update since I think that will have all the commands you seem to be looking for. Here's an article that may help:

http://www.petri.co.il/alternative-command-shells_for-windows.htm

Here's Microsoft's article on their Command shell overview:

https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

I hope that clears it up a little. Sorry if that's not what you were asking.

Comment: No. Linux usually uses Bash, and Windows uses `cmd.exe` (`command.com` is obsolete)

Comment: The OP already has Powershell.